# Subtract Overlaps Between Two Ranges Without Sets

Tags: python, range, overlap

**NO SETS!**

I can't use Sets because:

- The ranges will be too long.
- They will take up too much memory
- The creation of the sets themselves will take too long.

---

Using only the endpoints of the of the ranges, is there an optimal way to subtract two lists of ranges?

#### Example:

```
r1 = (1, 1000), (1100, 1200)  
r2 = (30, 50), (60, 200), (1150, 1300)

r1 - r2 = (1, 29), (51, 59), (201, 1000), (1100, 1149)
```

#### Other info:

- r2 does not have to overlap r1
- r1 and r2 will not have pairs that overlap other pairs.  For instance, r1 will not have both (0,30) and (10, 25)

Thanks.

Comment: what if something in `r2` isn't in `r1` ?

Comment: Are we only dealing with Integers? What if we have `r1=(1.5, 5.1)` and `r2 = (2.5, 4.3)`? How exactly should we deal with this?

Comment: @JBernardo: r2 can contain ranges that have no overlap with r1

Comment: @jmlopez: Personally, I will only be using integers.  I have a fxn that does this now for subtracting genome sequences.  I'm curious if there is an optimal way of doing it.

Comment: FWIW, I have been working on (as part of a larger project - and this part hasn't been looked at in a while) an implementation of a class that seems to do what you want...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [interval](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval/1.0.0) package may provide all that you need.

```
from interval import Interval, IntervalSet
r1 = IntervalSet([Interval(1, 1000), Interval(1100, 1200)])
r2 = IntervalSet([Interval(30, 50), Interval(60, 200), Interval(1150, 1300)])
print(r1 - r2)

>>> [1..30),(50..60),(200..1000],[1100..1150)
```

Comment: Yeah, though I don't know how well supported that code seems to be.  It says it was last updated 6 years ago...

Comment: It may not have been updated in part because it hasn't needed to be: it appears to be well-written with lots of tests.  And, since it's open source, you can maintain it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome and would have saved me about two days working through all the exceptions in the script I wrote.  FYI to everyone else, to get the lowest or highest number in an Interval just do Interval.lower_bound or Interval.upper_bound.

Comment: What about the no sets requirement? Is IntervalSet creation O(n)?

Comment: This is a nice solution but unfortunately, does not work for Python3...

Comment: when trying to work with this in python 2, it gives the following error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Interval' and 'Interval'. Any solution for that?

Comment: same on python3

Answer (score 11):

This was an interesting problem!

I think this is right, and it's fairly compact. It should work with overlapping ranges of all kinds, but it assumes well-formed ranges (i.e. `[x, y)` where `x < y`). It uses `[x, y)` style ranges for simplicity. It's based on the observation that there are really only six possible arrangements (with results in ()):

**Edit**: I found a more compact representation:

```
(s1 e1)  s2 e2
(s1 s2)  e1 e2
(s1 s2) (e2 e1)

 s2 e2  (s1 e1)
 s2 s1  (e2 e1)
 s2 s1   e1 e2 ()
```

Given a sorted list of endpoints, if `endpoints[0] == s1` then the first two endpoints should be in the result. If `endpoints[3] == e1` then the last two endpoints should be in the result. If neither, then there should be no result.

I haven't tested it a great deal, so it's entirely possible that something is wrong. Please let me know if you find a mistake!

```
import itertools

def range_diff(r1, r2):
    s1, e1 = r1
    s2, e2 = r2
    endpoints = sorted((s1, s2, e1, e2))
    result = []
    if endpoints[0] == s1 and endpoints[1] != s1:
        result.append((endpoints[0], endpoints[1]))
    if endpoints[3] == e1 and endpoints[2] != e1:
        result.append((endpoints[2], endpoints[3]))
    return result

def multirange_diff(r1_list, r2_list):
    for r2 in r2_list:
        r1_list = list(itertools.chain(*[range_diff(r1, r2) for r1 in r1_list]))
    return r1_list
```

Tested:

```
>>> r1_list = [(1, 1001), (1100, 1201)]
>>> r2_list = [(30, 51), (60, 201), (1150, 1301)]
>>> print multirange_diff(r1_list, r2_list)
[(1, 30), (51, 60), (201, 1001), (1100, 1150)]
```

Comment: The bounds on those ranges are not correct.  They are off-by-one due to the fact that the inputs are *closed* ranges (I know because I made this mistake myself too :).

Comment: @Mikola: Well, the text of the answer does state that the intervals being used are closed-left, open-right.  It is simple enough to convert the input beforehand to what this answer needs, and then convert the output afterward to what the OP needs.

Comment: Yes, @John, exactly. @Mikola, I concluded it was more idiomatic (in python) to use half-closed, `range()`-style ranges; to get the OP's input and output, convert the above to closed ranges by subtracting one from the last number in each case -- a trivial operation "left to the reader" :).

Comment: I would agree.  In fact, that is how I initially wrote my solution too.  Honestly, using closed ranges is probably a disastrous mistake (from a design/debugging perspective), but it is what the OP asksed for so I felt that I should oblige.

Comment: The representation is absolutely genius!

Answer (score 5):

One solution (in addition to all the other different solutions that have been presented here) is to use an interval/segment tree (they are really the same thing):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

One big advantage to doing it this way is that it is trivial to do arbitrary boolean operations (not just subtraction) using the same piece of code.  There is a standard treatment of this data structure in de Berg.  To perform any boolean operation on a pair of interval trees, (including subtraction) you just merge them together.  Here is some (admittedly naive) Python code for doing this with unbalanced range trees.  The fact that they are unbalanced has no effect on the time taken to merge the trees, however the tree construction here is the really dumb part which ends up being quadratic (unless the reduce is executed by partitioning, which I somehow doubt).  Anyway here you go:

```
class IntervalTree:
    def __init__(self, h, left, right):
        self.h = h
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def merge(A, B, op, l=-float("inf"), u=float("inf")):
    if l > u:
        return None
    if not isinstance(A, IntervalTree):
        if isinstance(B, IntervalTree):
            opT = op
            A, B, op = B, A, (lambda x, y : opT(y,x))
        else:
            return op(A, B)
    left = merge(A.left, B, op, l, min(A.h, u))
    right = merge(A.right, B, op, max(A.h, l), u)
    if left is None:
        return right
    elif right is None or left == right:
        return left
    return IntervalTree(A.h, left, right)

def to_range_list(T, l=-float("inf"), u=float("inf")):
    if isinstance(T, IntervalTree):
        return to_range_list(T.left, l, T.h) + to_range_list(T.right, T.h, u)
    return [(l, u-1)] if T else []

def range_list_to_tree(L):
    return reduce(lambda x, y : merge(x, y, lambda a, b: a or b), 
        [ IntervalTree(R[0], False, IntervalTree(R[1]+1, True, False)) for R in L ])
```

I wrote this kind of quickly and didn't test it that much, so there could be bugs.  Also note that this code will work with arbitrary boolean operations, not just differences (you simply pass them as the argument to op in merge).  The time complexity of evaluating any of these is linear on the size of the output tree (which is also the same as the number of intervals in the result).  As an example, I ran it on the case you provided:

```
#Example:
r1 = range_list_to_tree([ (1, 1000), (1100, 1200) ])
r2 = range_list_to_tree([ (30, 50), (60, 200), (1150, 1300) ])
diff = merge(r1, r2, lambda a, b : a and not b)
print to_range_list(diff)
```

And I got the following output:

> [(1, 29), (51, 59), (201, 1000), (1100, 1149)]

Which seems to be in agreement with what you would expect.  Now if you want to do some other boolean operations here is how it would work using the same function:

```
#Intersection
merge(r1, r2, lambda a, b : a and b)

#Union
merge(r1, r2, lambda a, b : a or b)

#Xor
merge(r1, r2, lambda a, b : a != b)
```

Comment: @senderle:  Thanks!  Technically the data structure is a 1D BSP tree.  This merge algorithm is actually based on one that I published back when I was an undergrad.  Here is a PDF link:  http://sal-cnc.me.wisc.edu/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=143&func=fileinfo&id=172

Answer (score 3):

I think I misunderstood the question, but this code works if `r2` is a subset of `r1`

```
class RangeSet:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.ranges = list(elements)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.ranges)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'RangeSet: %r' % self.ranges

    def has(self, tup):
        for pos, i in enumerate(self.ranges):
            if i[0] <= tup[0] and i[1] >= tup[1]:
                return pos, i
        raise ValueError('Invalid range or overlapping range')

    def minus(self, tup):
        pos, (x,y) = self.has(tup)
        out = []
        if x < tup[0]:
            out.append((x, tup[0]-1))
        if y > tup[1]:
            out.append((tup[1]+1, y))
        self.ranges[pos:pos+1] = out

    def __sub__(self, r):
        r1 = RangeSet(self)
        for i in r: r1.minus(i)
        return r1

    def sub(self, r): #inplace subtraction
        for i in r:
            self.minus(i)
```

then, you do:

**Update**: Note the last interval of `r2` is different to work the way I meant.

```
>>> r1 = RangeSet(((1, 1000), (1100, 1200)))
>>> r2 = RangeSet([(30, 50), (60, 200), (1150, 1200)])
>>> r1 - r2
RangeSet: [(1, 29), (51, 59), (201, 1000), (1100, 1149)]
>>> r1.sub(r2)
>>> r1
RangeSet: [(1, 29), (51, 59), (201, 1000), (1100, 1149)]
```

Comment: the expected answer does not include `(1181, 1200)`

Comment: @Dan that's a different set. It looks odd for me to don't accept overlapping in the middle but do it at the end

Comment: oh you used an example that was overly similar to the given example and that confused me; i considered that this was exactly interval subtraction: `(1100, 1200) - (1150, 1300) = (1100, 1149)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick python function that does the subtraction, regardless of whether the initial lists are well-formed (i.e. turns the lists into the smallest list of equivalent ranges, sorted, before doing the subtraction):

```
def condense(l):
    l = sorted(l)
    temp = [l.pop(0)]
    for t in l:
        if t[0] <= temp[-1][1]:
            t2 = temp.pop()
            temp.append((t2[0], max(t[1], t2[1])))
        else:
            temp.append(t)
    return temp

def setSubtract(l1, l2):
    l1 = condense(l1)
    l2 = condense(l2)
    i = 0
    for t in l2:
        while t[0] > l1[i][1]:
            i += 1
            if i >= len(l1):
                break
        if t[1] < l1[i][1] and t[0] > l1[i][0]:
            #t cuts l1[i] in 2 pieces
            l1 = l1[:i] + [(l1[i][0], t[0] - 1), (t[1] + 1, l1[i][1])] + l1[i + 1:]
        elif t[1] >= l1[i][1] and t[0] <= l1[i][0]:
            #t eliminates l1[i]
            l1.pop(i)
        elif t[1] >= l1[i][1]:
            #t cuts off the top end of l1[i]
            l1[i] = (l1[i][0], t[0] - 1)
        elif t[0] <= l1[i][0]:
            #t cuts off the bottom end of l1[i]
            l1[i] = (t[1] + 1, l1[i][1])
        else:
            print "This shouldn't happen..."
            exit()
    return l1

r1 = (1, 1000), (1100, 1200)
r2 = (30, 50), (60, 200), (1150, 1300)
setSubtract(r1, r2) #yields [(1, 29), (51, 59), (201, 1000), (1100, 1149)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun question!  Another implementation, though you already have plenty.  It was interesting to do!
Involves some extra 'decoration' to make what I'm doing more explicit.

```
import itertools

def flatten_range_to_labeled_points(input_range,label):
    range_with_labels = [((start,'start_%s'%label),(end,'end_%s'%label)) for (start,end) in input_range]
    flattened_range = list(reduce(itertools.chain,range_with_labels))
    return flattened_range 

def unflatten_range_remove_labels(input_range):
    without_labels = [x for (x,y) in input_range]
    grouped_into_pairs = itertools.izip(without_labels[::2], without_labels[1::2])
    return grouped_into_pairs

def subtract_ranges(range1, range2):
    range1_labeled = flatten_range_to_labeled_points(range1,1)
    range2_labeled = flatten_range_to_labeled_points(range2,2)
    all_starts_ends_together = sorted(range1_labeled + range2_labeled)
    in_range1, in_range2 = False, False
    new_starts_ends = []
    for (position,label) in all_starts_ends_together:
        if label=='start_1':
            in_range1 = True
            if not in_range2:
                new_starts_ends.append((position,'start'))
        elif label=='end_1':
            in_range1 = False
            if not in_range2:
                new_starts_ends.append((position,'end'))
        elif label=='start_2':
            in_range2 = True
            if in_range1:
                new_starts_ends.append((position-1,'end'))
        elif label=='end_2':
            in_range2 = False
            if in_range1:
                new_starts_ends.append((position+1,'start'))
    # strip the start/end labels, they're not used, I just appended them for clarity
    return unflatten_range_remove_labels(new_starts_ends)
```

I get the right output:

```
r1 = (1, 1000), (1100, 1200)
r2 = (30, 50), (60, 200), (1150, 1300)
>>> subtract_ranges(r1,r2)
[(1, 29), (51, 59), (201, 1000), (1100, 1149)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
[interval](https://pypi.org/project/interval/1.0.0/), use
[python-ranges](https://pypi.org/project/python-ranges/)

```
from ranges import Range, RangeSet
r1 = RangeSet([Range(1, 1000), Range(1100, 1200)])
r2 = RangeSet([Range(30, 50), Range(60, 200), Range(1150, 1300)])
print(r1 - r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is rather ugly but it does work for the given example

```
def minus1(a,b):
    if (b[0] < a[0] and b[1] < a[0]) or (a[1] < b[0] and a[1] < b[1]):
        return [a] # doesn't overlap
    if a[0]==b[0] and a[1]==b[1]:
        return [] # overlaps exactly
    if b[0] < a[0] and a[1] < b[1]:
        return [] # overlaps completely
    if a[0]==b[0]:
        return [(b[1]+1,a[1])] # overlaps exactly on the left
    if a[1]==b[1]:
        return [(a[0],b[0]-1)] # overlaps exactly on the right 
    if a[0] < b[0] and b[0] < a[1] and a[1] < b[1]:
        return [(a[0],b[0]-1)] # overlaps the end
    if a[0] < b[1] and b[1] < a[1] and b[0] < a[0]:
        return [(b[1]+1,a[1])] # overlaps the start
    else:
        return [(a[0],b[0]-1),(b[1]+1,a[1])] # somewhere in the middle

def minus(r1, r2):
    # assume r1 and r2 are already sorted
    r1 = r1[:]
    r2 = r2[:]
    l = []
    v = r1.pop(0)
    b = r2.pop(0)
    while True:
        r = minus1(v,b)
        if r:
            if len(r)==1:
                if r[0] == v:
                    if v[1] < b[0] and v[1] < b[1]:
                        l.append(r[0])
                        if r1:
                            v = r1.pop(0)
                        else:
                            break
                    else:
                        if r2:
                            b = r2.pop(0)
                        else:
                            break
                else:
                    v = r[0]
            else:
                l.append(r[0])
                v = r[1]
                if r2:
                    b = r2.pop(0)
                else:
                    l.append(v)
                    break
        else:
            if r1:
                v = r1.pop(0)
            else:
                break
            if r2:
                b = r2.pop(0)
            else:
                l.append(v)
                l.extend(r1)
                break
    return l

r1 = [(1, 1000), (1100, 1200)]
r2 = [(30, 50), (60, 200), (1150, 1300)]

print minus(r1,r2)
```

prints:

```
[(1, 29), (51, 59), (201, 1000), (1100, 1149)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [portion](https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion) which supports python3

```
import portion as P

r1 = P.closedopen(1, 1000) |  P.closedopen(1100, 1200)
r2 = P.closedopen(30, 50) | P.closedopen(60, 200) | P.closedopen(1150, 1300)
print(r1 - r2)
```