# Subtracting overlap of ranges in Python

Tags: python-3.x, range

I have a question which has been asked before here:
[Subtract Overlaps Between Two Ranges Without Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462272/subtract-overlaps-between-two-ranges-without-sets), however, the solution provided there seems to be outdated and gives me the following error:

```
from interval import Interval, IntervalSet
r1 = IntervalSet([Interval(1, 1000), Interval(1100, 1200)])
r2 = IntervalSet([Interval(30, 50), Interval(60, 200), Interval(1150, 1300)])
print(r1 - r2)
```

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Interval' and 'Interval'

I am working with python 3.6. I've searched a lot but I could not find why this problem is arising. I would appreciate any hint to solve this problem.

Comment: It simply means that you cannot use the `<` on an `Interval` object. If you need this functionality you should file an issue with the maintainer(s) of the package.

Comment: Or subclass Interval and implement the `<` operator to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

If you read a bit on, you"ll see that the solution you posted from @Ned Deily isn't working for python 3. Then you will also see different approaches and solutions to this problem, so you can try some and see which one works for you, like this answer posted by @senderle in that very link:

```
import itertools

def range_diff(r1, r2):
    s1, e1 = r1
    s2, e2 = r2
    endpoints = sorted((s1, s2, e1, e2))
    result = []
    if endpoints[0] == s1:
        result.append((endpoints[0], endpoints[1]))
    if endpoints[3] == e1:
        result.append((endpoints[2], endpoints[3]))
    return result

def multirange_diff(r1_list, r2_list):
    for r2 in r2_list:
        r1_list = list(itertools.chain(*[range_diff(r1, r2) for r1 in r1_list]))
    return r1_list
```

I've tried it with succes, you can see for yourself if the other answers are also working for you.