# Subtract smaller time intervals from a big time interval range

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

- I want to obtain the time intervals subtracting the time windows from the timeline. Is there an efficient way using pandas Intervals and periods.
- I tried to looking for a solution using pandas periods and Intervals class on SO but could not found such maybe because Intervals are immutable objects in pandas (ref https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html#pandas-interval).
- I found a relevant solution using 3rd party library [Subtract Overlaps Between Two Ranges Without Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462272/subtract-overlaps-between-two-ranges-without-sets) But it does not particularly deals using `datetime` or `Timestamp` objects.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

start = pd.Timestamp('00:00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('23:59:00')

# input
big_time_interval = pd.Interval(start, end)

smaller_time_intervals_to_subtract = [
    (pd.Timestamp('01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('02:00:00')),
    (pd.Timestamp('16:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('17:00:00'))]


# output
_output_time_intervals = [
    (pd.Timestamp('00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('01:00:00')),
    (pd.Timestamp('02:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('16:00:00')),
    (pd.Timestamp('17:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('23:59:00'))]

output_time_intervals = list(
    map(lambda interval: pd.Interval(*interval), _output_time_intervals))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just convert your time formatting into seconds from midnight then use the overlap subtracting library.

Comment: Can you show your input and expected output?

Comment: @Datanovice I've added a reproducible example in the recent edit.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated I'd lose the time beginning say the date or year. information if I expand my example to handle multiple dates. I do not want to loose that information at the same time.

Comment: @AkarshJain then just convert all of it to unix epoch