# Splitting ranges according to list of excluded ranges

Tags: python

I have two arrays:

```
ranges  = [[50, 60], [100, 100], [5000, 6000]]
exclude = [[1000, 1000], [5060, 5060]]
```

How to get the result as a sorted list that is

```
[[50, 60], [100, 100], [5000, 5059], [5061, 6000]]
```

Basically, remove the ranges of the second list from the ranges of the first list, creating new ranges where needed.

More examples:

```
ranges  = [[2, 124235]]
exclude = [[2000, 3000], [400, 2500]]
```

that gives me output

```
[[2, 399], [3001, 124235]]
```

Comment: Did you try anything that you actually need help with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract Overlaps Between Two Ranges Without Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462272/subtract-overlaps-between-two-ranges-without-sets)